# MySQL select latest record in group

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL retrieve latest record for Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444167/mysql-retrieve-latest-record-for-group)

I have a query that groups all records that have the same information in the 'address1' field, unless they have a different jobType.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   jobs 
WHERE  client_id = '".$id."' 
       AND status = '3' 
GROUP  BY CASE 
            WHEN jobType IN ( '0', '3', '6' ) THEN '0' 
            ELSE jobType 
          end, 
          address1 
ORDER  BY Max(id) ASC
```

The problem I'm running into, is that the query always pulls the first instance in the group. I need it to pull the latest instance in the group. I've tried a few variations of ORDER BY, and that hasn't seemed to do the trick.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe wrap the query in another select statement with the order by clause and then group by on that

Comment: @nathanhayfield: ["*The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which values the server chooses.*"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Comment: thats why you order by in an inner select statement...

Comment: @nathanhayfield: And yet, even then, the values chosen are **indeterminate**.

Comment: it still works in mysql but its not really supposed to...

Comment: It doesn't always work.  If one has a hash index, for example...

Comment: There are no "first" or "latest" rows in SQL tables, unless there is a datetime (or timestamp) column to track time.

Comment: @ypercube: Given `ORDER BY MAX(id) ASC` in the OP's query, one assumes that is the ordering by which he wishes to determine "latest"?

Comment: I do have a datetime column, as well as sequential ids. How could I go about using these to select the latest item in the group?

Comment: @ypercube There are no latest records in the table, but there are in the query, since you can apply specific sorting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT jobs.*
FROM   jobs NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   MAX(id) id
  FROM     jobs
  WHERE    client_id = :id AND status = '3'
  GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN jobType IN ('0','3','6') THEN '0'
             ELSE jobType
           END,
           address1
) t
```

However, this won't be very index-friendly.  Better to create a column that contains the result of your `CASE` expression (and then index that).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't appear to work as posted. I've added in `WHERE client_id = '".$id."' AND status = '3'`, so it only selects records for that specific client, but it doesn't appear to be grouping the records at all anymore. I now see all records under that client.

Comment: @Jeremy: See my updated answer above.